# GridView: order column, show/hide columns

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

OK... so I'm trying to display data from a table in my DB using a GridView. I need to change the display order of the columns and I need to show/hide certain columns depending on the language the user is browsing the site in (French or English).

So far in my code I have this. The data is loading via a DataSource.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    LoadS25ATransactionsData()

End Sub


Private Sub LoadS25ATransactionsData()

    gvS25ATransactions.Visible = True
    gvS25ATransactions.DataSource = ViewS25A.GetS25ATransactions
    gvS25ATransactions.DataBind()

End Sub
```

I've tried a bunch of things to change the order of the columns and hide and show other but to no avail. Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GridView.Columns[0] to hide a column by index or hide by the name like the following example.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPreRender="GridView_PreRender">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var users = new List<User>
            {
                new User {FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"},
                new User {FirstName = "Marry", LastName = "Newton"},
                new User {FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Black"}
            };

        GridView1.DataSource = users;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataControlField column in GridView1.Columns)
        if (column.HeaderText == "FirstName")
            column.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Made a few changes to the code you provided and it worked great! Thank you for sending me in the right direction!